# How to manipulate two data sets in DateListPlot with a dynamic x-axes

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm new in Wolfram Mathematica and could not find an answer to a very basic question.
Currently I working with a large number of data. The data are imported from Excel with a small
sample, see below.
My question is how to manipulate this two data sets in one DateListPlot with one slider?

data1 =
{{{2006, 01, 01} , 27}, {{2006, 01, 02}, 25}, {{2006, 01, 03}, 86}, {{2006, 01, 04}, 72}, {{2006, 01, 05}, 66}, {{2006, 01, 06}, {{2006, 01, 07}, 13}}

data2=
{{{2006, 01, 01} , 33}, {{2006, 01, 02}, 36}, {{2006, 01, 03},100}, {{2006, 01, 04}, 100}, {{2006, 01, 05}, 76}, {{2006, 01, 06}, {{2006, 01, 07}, 27}}

Can someone help?
Your support will be highly appreciated!
JK

Answer (score 0):

If you type `?<symbol>` into Mathematica, you’ll get short summary help for `<symbol>`. In the case of `DateListPlot`, Mathematica says:

> DateListPlot[{list1, list2, ...}] plots several lists of values.

So you can write `DateListPlot[{data1, data2}]` to get a combined plot of both lists:

[image]

Comment: I assume there is a misunderstanding. What I needed is to Manipulate two sets of data columns (a/m are just a small sample out of my data of 3000 entries. The Manipulate code for column 'data 1' (called ‘Severity’) works fine and is: 
`Manipulate[DateListPlot[data1[[1;;Severity]],Joined->True],{Severity,1,Length[data1],1}]`
 but will not work with two columns of data. My question is can someone help to find the Manipulate code for columns 'data1' and 'data2' in one graph with one slider?

Comment: `Manipulate[DateListPlot[{data1[[1;;Severity]],data2[[1;;Severity]]},Joined->True],{Severity,1,Length[d‌​ata1],1}]` ?